Screen space refraction option seems to be in Blender 4.1.1
The screen space refraction option is missing in the material settings tab.
Am I missing somthing or is there a way to get the same result another way?
In the Blender doc it says it is still supposed to be there.

It's an option in Eevee, not Cycles

Not sure what the title is supposed to mean.

Screen Space Refraction is an option available in Eevee, not Cycles, you are probably in Cycles
